# Exercise 10, Section 6.6 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, projection

> Let $F$ be a subfield of the complex numbers (or, a field of characteristic zero). Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $F$. Suppose that $E_1,…,E_k$ are projections of $V$ and that $E_1+…+E_k=I$. Prove that $E_iE_j=0$ for $i\neq j$ (Hint: Use the trace function and ask yourself what the trace of a projection is)

**My attempt:** We use induction approach. $\forall k\geq 2$, $P(k)$: If $E_1,…,E_k$ are projection of $V$ and $E_1+…+E_k=I$, then $E_iE_j\neq 0$, if $i\neq j$. Base case: $k=2$. Suppose $E_1,E_2$ are projection and  $E_1+E_2=I$. Then $E_1(E_1+E_2)=E_1^2+E_1E_2=E_1$. Since $E_1^2=E_1$, we have $E_1E_2=0$. Similarly $E_2E_1=0$. Inductive step: Suppose $P(k)$ is true for some $k\geq 2$. Suppose $E_1,…,E_{k+1}$ are projection of $V$ and $E_1+…+E_{k+1}=I$. Let $i\in J_k$. Then $E_i(E_1+…+E_{k+1})=E_iE_1+…+E_iE_{k+1}=E_i$. By inductive hypothesis, $E_iE_1+…+E_iE_{k+1} =E_i^2+E_iE_{k+1}=E_i$. Since $E_i^2=E_i$, we have $E_iE_{k+1}=0$. Similarly $E_{k+1}E_i=0$. Thus $E_iE_{k+1}=E_{k+1}E_i=0$, $\forall i\in J_k$. Hence $E_iE_j=0$, $i\neq j$. By principle of mathematical induction, $P(k)$ is true $\forall k\geq 2$. **Is my proof correct?**

Can we use induction on if-then statement? My proof is probably wrong, because I only used then part of induction hypothesis (i.e. $E_iE_j=0$, if $1\leq i\lt j\leq n$) without showing $E_1+…+E_k=I$.

Comment: I do not follow your argument by induction. First of all how do you know beforehand that $E_iE_j$ is a projection for $i\neq j$ ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Our goal is to show $E_iE_j=0$. I think we don’t care about if $E_iE_j$ is projection or not.

Comment: Your induction argument requires that $E_iE_j$ is a projection.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Where exactly are you using $E_iE_j$ is projection? Inductive hypothesis is, $E_1,…,E_k$ are projection and $E_1+…+E_k=I$$\implies$$E_iE_j=0$, if $i\neq j$ and $i,j\in J_k$. In my proof I used, $E_iE_j=0$, if $i\neq j$ and $i,j\in J_k$ without showing $E_1+…+E_k=I$. That’s why my induction proof is most likely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality
$$E_1+E_2+\ldots +E_k=I\qquad (*)$$ implies that the linear span of $\{{\rm Im}\,E_j\}_{j=1}^k$  is equal to $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or $\mathbb{C}^n).$ The trace of a projection is equal to the dimension of its range.
Let $d_j$ denote the range of $E_j.$ Then $(*)$ gives
$$d_1+d_2+\ldots +d_k={\rm Tr}\,I=n\quad (**)$$
The formulas $(*)$ and $(**)$ imply that the subspaces ${\rm Im}\,E_j$ are linearly independent.
For any vector $v$ w get  $$E_1v+E_2E_1v+\ldots +E_nE_1v=E_1v$$ hence
$$E_2E_1v+\ldots +E_nE_1v=0$$
As the ranges of $E_2,\ldots, E_n$ are linearly independent, we get $E_2E_1v=\ldots =E_nE_1v=0.$ Thus $E_2E_1=\ldots =E_nE_1=0.$
The enumeration of the projections is irrelevant, hence $E_iE_j=0$ for any $i\neq j.$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will again try my best to prove this exercise using trace function before looking at your solution.

Comment: @user264745 His solutions **is** based on trace function.

Comment: As a side note, wouldn't it be better to hide the answer with spoilers? I'm sure the OP would be more appreciative of hints, and checking whether their solution is correct, rather than a complete answer.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. complete answer always helps.

Comment: @user264745 Well, I'm not saying that it doesn't, I'm suggesting that he hide it behind a spoiler. But then again, it's your question, so it's up to you. Personally I do get annoyed when someone answers a solution verification question outright, without even addressing the question poster's solution or providing hints first.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. I do not mind hiding the answer in a spoiler but copy and paste does not work for spoilers. I am too lazy to re-type all the content.